# How to define a const on the singleton class?

Tags: ruby

I want to define a constant for a single instance of an object, not for all instances of an object.

```
class MyTest
  def call
    Foo
  end
end

t = MyTest.new

t.call # => NameError (as expected)

t.singleton_class.class_eval do
  const_set 'Foo', 'foo'
end

t.singleton_class::Foo # => 'foo'
t.call # => NameError
```

Why does the const lookup not include the const defined in the objects singleton class?

Here is another attempt:

```
Dog = Class.new { def call; Bark; end }
d = Dog.new
d.call # => NameError (expected)
d.singleton_class.const_set('Bark', 'woof')
d.call # => NameError (not expected)
```

Comment: Maybe `singleton_class.class_eval` is eval-ing in the context of `Class` (i.e the singelton classes class), not the "singleton class" itself...

Comment: You have defined `Foo` inside the singleton class of `t`, not in `MyTest` class.

Comment: I want to define to a const for an object, `t` in this case, not for all instances of `MyTest`. I will update the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The constant has been defined in the instance's singleton class but `Foo` doesn't include `(singleton_class)::Foo` in one of its possible evaluations so specify it explicitly:

```
class MyTest
  def call
    singleton_class::Foo
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is not possible:

- `const_set` is defined on `Module`
- Ruby looks for constant in `nesting` and `ancestors`

There is no place where to define the constant for a `MyTest` instance

```
class MyTest
  def call
    puts (Module.nesting + Module.ancestors).uniq.inspect
  end
end
MyTest.new.call
# => [MyTest, Module, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Comment: I think this is potentially the right answer, while constants can be defined on the singleton class, Ruby does not look for constants there. That said it does not explain why `t.singleton_class.instance_eval { Foo = 'foo' }` works.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050397/how-to-define-a-const-on-the-singleton-class#comment46338856_29050397) is correct - `t.singleton_class.class_eval` first gets the `singleton_class` of `t` and then `eval`s something on that singleton classes' class.

Instead what you want is to define the constant on the *instance* of that singleton class, like so:

```
t.singleton_class.instance_eval do
  Foo = 'foo'
end
```

After that, `t.call` returns `"foo"`.

Comment: Interestingly `self` in `instance_eval` and `class_eval` is the same object. But defining `Foo` statically instead of dynamically, using `const_set`, does work.

Comment: @Kris that's because it's actually defining a global constant.

Answer (score 0):

Start be creating an arbitrary set and an instance of that set.

```
class A; end

a = A.new
  #=> #<A:0x00007ff0bbaa9f98>
```

For convenience, assign `a`'s singleton class<sup>1</sup> to a variable.

```
as = a.singleton_class
  #=> #<Class:#<A:0x00007ff0bbaa9f98>>
```

Create a constant in `as` whose value equals `3`.

```
as.const_set(:A, 3)
  #=> 3
```

Check that the constant was defined.

```
as.constants
  #=> [:A]
```

Let's check its value also.

```
as.const_get(:A)
  #=> 3
```

Now let's create a method in `as` that references the constant we've created.

```
as.define_method(:cat) { puts "#{as.const_get(:A)} cats"}
  #=> :cat
```

Try it.

```
a.cat
  #=> "3 cats"
```

See [Module#const_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-const_set) and [Module#const_get](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-const_get).

<sup>1. Every Ruby object has a singleton class. Singleton classes are like regular classes except they cannot be subclassed and one cannot create instances of subclasses.</sup>